# Document in Word does not have default styles

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

I opened a document already created and the default styles were not present.  I set the styles to "default black and white" but there is still no "Normal" style. There is just a "Normal; chapter sub heading style."  If I open a new document, of course all the defaults are there.  How do I restore those same defaults to my already created file?

Answer (score 1):

1. Bring up the “Styles” dialog box by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>,
   or by clicking on the arrow button in the bottom right corner of the “Styles” panel
   on the “Home” tab of the ribbon.
2. Click on the “Manage Styles” button at the bottom of the “Styles” dialog box:

   [image: “Styles” dialog box]
3. Click on the “Import/Export…” button at the bottom of the “Manage Styles” dialog box.
4. The “Organizer” dialog box will let you copy styles between documents:

   [image: “Organizer” dialog box]

Comment: This doesn't let you copy heading styles though?